# Swift custom tableview cell does not have my image property?

Tags: swift2, uitableview

I am trying to follow this video's guide on creating my own custom tableView cells

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVJiprvRLoo

however, when I am doing the cell.photo.image part, Xcode tells me that UITableViewCell has no member 'photo'

Did i forgot to connect something to somewhere??

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You forgot to create `outlet` of `UIImageView` in your `CustomCell`. Create that and bind it with the `prototypeCell`. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem will be solved.youtube video guide is correct but watch it carefully till end. try this code below. photo properties of uiimageview not uiview.

```
 class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var breed: UILabel!

              }
//   Next class 





  class Dog: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)   -> Int {

        return Names.count
    }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:       NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: thanks! I saw what I did wrong when I was declaring my cell variable!